# Android GCM start specific Activity fails

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have this code to generate a notification from inside the GCM-Service:

```
private void sendNotification(Bundle extras) {
    int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

    String notification_type = extras.getString("type");

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, extras.getString("message"), when);

    String title = this.getString(R.string.app_name);


    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, InvitationActivity.class);
    if ( notification_type != null && notification_type.equals("invitation"))
    {
        notificationIntent = new Intent(this, InvitationActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("lobby_id", Integer.valueOf(extras.getString("messagedata", "0")));
    } else {
        notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    }



    // set intent so it does not start a new activity
    //notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
    //        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent intent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, title, extras.getString("message"), intent);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    // Play default notification sound
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

    // Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
}
```

The Problem is that MainActivity starts if I click on the notification, however if

```
notificationIntent = new Intent(this, InvitationActivity.class);
```

is called and I tap on the notification, nothing seems to happen, no error, no activity is launched. This only occurs with InvitationActivity, Mainactivity is working fine.

InvitationActivity:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_invitation);



    lobby_id = getIntent().getIntExtra("lobby_id", 0);
```

EDIT:
AndroidManifest.xml:

```
 <activity
        android:name=".activities_fragments.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
<activity
        android:name=".activities_fragments.InvitationActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_invitation"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog">
    </activity>
```

The strange thing is, if I start InvitationActivity from within MainActivity it works as expected, but not from inside the GCMService.

Comment: Can you show the declaration of MainActivity and InvitationActivity in your manifest?

Comment: Sure, you'll find it above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

```
android:exported="true"
```

Inside your invitationActivity tag like this:

```
<activity
    android:name=".activities_fragments.InvitationActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_invitation"
    android:exported="true"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog">
</activity>
```

This will resolve your issue